# Watin File Download Problem

Tags: file, download, watin

When I clicked button with mouse, File Download Dialog opens directly. But when Watin Button Click methods click the vert same button on same ie window this message appears and wait my confirm

> To help protect your security,
>   Internet Explorer blocked this site
>   from downloading files to your
>   computer. Click here for options.

I turned off the Information bar for file downloads,(Internet Options-Security-Custom Level-Downloads-Automatic prompting for file downloads-->Enable),allow active x content, lower security level for internet etc.. but didn't work.

I'm using Win 7, IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution : there is a bug in Internet Explorer 8 : settings for information bar file downloads are inversed.

It says "prompt for file download" but when you set it to "disable", it prompts; and when you set it to "enable" it doesn't !

So, the solution is : go to [Internet Options|Security|Custom Level|Downloads|Ask confirmation for fiel downloads] and set it to "Enable"

Answer (score 1):

Also, try `MouseDown()` instead of `Click()`.. it might act differently

Comment: Thanks much for this, I had a somewhat similar problem and this saved me quite a headache

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your domain to trusted ones. This is in Internet Options. Unfortunately I don't have english version of Windows to point you directly to those settings.

Comment: also tried that, didn't work. As i said,interestingly, when i click with mouse pointer, works fine, dialog open directly. Somehow,when watin click the button, ie knows that command not come from user...